# AlertDialog not working when the data is null

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm learning building a weather app with flutter.

The app could display weather data for the current location, and display AlertDialog when there is no weather data (null)

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:clima/services/weather.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'city_screen.dart';

class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LocationScreen({this.locationWeather});

  final locationWeather;
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();
  String weatherMessage;
  String cityName;
  int temperature;
  String weatherIcon;
  bool weatherCondition = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateUI(widget.locationWeather);
  }

  dynamic updateUI(dynamic weatherData) {
    if (weatherData == null) {
      temperature = 0;
      weatherIcon = 'Error!';
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      double temp = weatherData['main']['temp'];
      temperature = temp.toInt();
      var conditionNumber = weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
      weatherIcon = weather.getWeatherIcon(conditionNumber);
      weatherMessage = weather.getMessage(temperature);
      cityName = weatherData['name'];
      return;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/location_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      var weatherData = await weather.getLocationWeather();
                      updateUI(weatherData);
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CityScreen()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_city,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '$temperature°',
                      style: kTempTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      weatherIcon,
                      style: kConditionTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              weatherCondition
                  ? Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 15.0, 40.0),
                      child: Text(
                        '$weatherMessage $cityName!',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                        style: kMessageTextStyle,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: showDialog(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                          content: Text('Unable to get weather data!'),
                          actions: [
                            RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                              child: Text('OK'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ) as Widget,
                    )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code didn't work, the IDE throwed the error : "Failed assertion: line 470 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true."

Hope someone can correct it to work properly.

Comment: You can't use `showDialog` result as widget.  You need to show the dialog after you have initialized or checking the related variables. Try moving it to `updateUI` in null checking part.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the required parameter for

```
showDialog(
  context: context, 
   builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            content: Text('Unable to get weather data!'),
            actions: [
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                child: Text('OK'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Note: you will face another Exception with this code , as u can't showDialog during the build of the UI